# PHP simpleXML, instead of appending, writes over everything

Tags: php, xml, loops, simplexml

I have an ongoing xml file, that when I call a php function to add a new child, it loops through an array of strings and queries a db to add a new child to the document and save it as the current string in the array. However, it is not appending, it is overwriting everything. Do I need to load the file first? and check if it exists?

```
function createUnitsXML($units,$wcccanumber,$mysqli) {

// Delete whitespaces and create an array of units assigned to call
$unit = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $units);
$unitsarray = explode(",",$unit);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($unitsarray); $i++) {

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE wcccanumber = '$wcccanumber'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $draw = $xml->addChild('call');
             $draw->addChild('wcccanumber',$row['wcccanumber']);
             $draw->addChild('currentcall',$row['call']);
             $draw->addChild('county',$row['county']);
             $draw->addChild('id',$row['id']);
             $draw->addChild('location',$row['location']);
             $draw->addChild('callcreated',$row['callcreated']);
             $draw->addChild('station',$row['station']);
             $draw->addChild('units',$row['units']);
             $draw->addChild('calltype',$row['calltype']);
             $draw->addChild('lat',$row['lat']);
             $draw->addChild('lng',$row['lng']);
             $draw->addChild('inputtime',$row['inputtime']);
        }
        $fp = fopen("xml/units/$unitsarray[$i].xml","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
        fclose($fp);
    }
    echo "--- Created units XML document for call: $wcccanumber";
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen("xml/units/$unitsarray[$i].xml","wb");
```

By opening the file as "wb", you are truncating the file to write. Try using "ab" (write-only, appends to end of file) or "ab+" (read or write, appends to end of file) instead.

Comment: This will create invalid XML files. Just noting.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, although it doesnt effect my application, how would I fix it?